# Unexpected error using newRequest in FunctionalTests

Tags: exception, playframework, functional-testing

I don't understand why I have this error.
When I use newRequest, I have a RuntimeException when calling the
makeRequest(request); method.

The exception message is : "**play.mvc.results.NotFound : POST /**"
But what is odd, is that in the .url, I specify "/dashboard", not
"/" (and of course, the url is well indicated in the routes file for POST requests!)

Thanks for your help.

Here is my test class :

```
public class DashboardTest extends FunctionalTest {
    protected Request ajaxRequest;

    @Before
    public void _setUp() {
        Fixtures.deleteDatabase();
        Fixtures.loadModels("fixtures/accounts.yml");

        ajaxRequest = newRequest();
        //ajaxRequest.headers.put("X-Requested-With", new Header("X-
Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"));
        ajaxRequest.method = "POST";
        ajaxRequest.url = "/dashboard";
    }

    @Test
    public void testAuthenticateWithValidDataAjax() {
        ajaxRequest.params.put("email", "john.sm...@gmail.com");

        Response response = makeRequest(ajaxRequest);
        assertIsOk(response);
        assertContentType("application/json", response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the API documentation, the `.url` specifies that it needs the Full URL. What I would suggest you do instead, is to use the `.action` instead.

The Javadoc for the this is

> Full action (ex: Application.index)

or specify the full URL, which would include

```
http://localhost:9000/dashboard
```

Your final option, if you are still having problems, is to use the `createRequest` method on the `Http.Request` object, which gives you complete control over the Request object you are creating. The signature looks like this

```
createRequest

public static Http.Request createRequest(java.lang.String _remoteAddress,
                                         java.lang.String _method,
                                         java.lang.String _path,
                                         java.lang.String _querystring,
                                         java.lang.String _contentType,
                                         java.io.InputStream _body,
                                         java.lang.String _url,
                                         java.lang.String _host,
                                         boolean _isLoopback,
                                         int _port,
                                         java.lang.String _domain,
                                         boolean _secure,
                                         java.util.Map<java.lang.String,Http.Header> _headers,
                                         java.util.Map<java.lang.String,Http.Cookie> _cookies)
```